# href tag not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

The following link is not working when you click it on my page:

```
<a href="www.youtube.com">Go to youtube</a>
```

I am not sure why this is because if you right click on it and tell it to open in a new window it works fine. I have a feeling the problem is somewhere in the Javascript but I can't see where and I am not sure how to fix it. The rest of my code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Modality jQuery PluginExample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modality.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1>Modality jQuery PluginExample</h1>
<!-- The trigger to open the modal --> 
<a href="#yourModalId">Open Modal</a> 

<!-- Your Modal, style it however you will! -->
<div id="yourModalId" style="display:none;">
      <div id="toppop">
      <div id="poptitle">Modality</div>
      <div id="popclose"><a href="#yourModalId">Close</a></div>
      <div id="toppopfooter"></div>
      </div>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">      
      .modality-modal.mm-show {
    background: rgba(250, 21, 139, 0.5);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 10000;
}
 </style>   
 <br>  
<a href="www.youtube.com">Go to youtube</a>
</div>
<script src="js/modality.js"></script>
    <script>
    var modal1 = Modality.init('#yourModalId', {
        effect: 'slide-up'
    });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    background-color: #000; 
}

.modality-modal {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden; 
    *zoom: 1;    
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
    transition: all 0.25s; 
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px; 
    -moz-perspective: 1000px; 
    perspective: 1000px; 
}
.mm-wrap {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;

    max-width: 94%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 10000;
    *zoom: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.modality-modal:before, .mm-ghost {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.modality-modal.mm-show .mm-wrap {
    opacity: 1;
}
body.mm-show { overflow: hidden; }

.yourModalClass {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 6px solid #FFF;
    width: 1044px;
    height: 742px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.yourModalClass #toppop {
    width: 1044px;
    height: 47px;
}

.yourModalClass #toppop #poptitle {
    width: 999px;
    height: 47px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 42px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    text-indent: 12px;
}

.yourModalClass #toppop #popclose {
    width: 45px;
    height: 47px;   
    float: left;
}

.yourModalClass #toppop #toppopfooter {
    width: 1044px;
    clear: both;    
}

.yourModalClass #WebImage {
    width: 1044px;
    height: 350px;
    text-align: center;
}

.yourModalClass #WebDescription {
    width: 1044px;
    height: 345px
}

/* Effect 1 & 2: scale up and down */
.scale-up .mm-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
}
.scale-down .mm-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
.mm-show.scale-up .mm-wrap,
.mm-show.scale-down .mm-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
;(function () {


    var _name = "Modality", 


        _body = document.querySelector('body'),


        _defaults = {
            autoBind: true, 
            clickOffToClose: true, 
            closeOnEscape: true, 
            effect: "", 
            innerClass: "mm-wrap", 
            modalClass: "modality-modal", 
            onClose: "", 
            onOpen: "", 
            openClass: "mm-show", 
            openOnLoad: false, 
            userClass: "" 
        }, 


    _extend = function () {
        var a = arguments;
        for( var i = 1; i < a.length; i++ )
            for( var key in a[i] )
                if(a[i].hasOwnProperty(key))
                    a[0][key] = a[i][key];
        return a[0];
    },


    _addEvent = function( target, event, fn ) {
        if ( target.attachEvent ) {
            target['e'+event+fn] = fn;
            target[event+fn] = function(){ target['e'+event+fn]( window.event ); }
            target.attachEvent( 'on'+event, target[event+fn] );
        } else {
           target.addEventListener( event, fn, false );
        }
    },


    hasClass = function( target, className ) {
        return target.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+className+'(\\s|$)'));
    },
    addClass = function( target, className ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < target.length; i++ )
            if( ! hasClass( target[i], className ) ) 
                target[i].className += " " + className;
    },
    removeClass = function( target, className ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < target.length; i++ ) {
            if( hasClass( target[i], className ) ) {
                var re = new RegExp("(\\s|^)" + className + "(\\s|$)", "g");
                target[i].className = target[i].className.replace(re , '');
            }
        }
    },


    _wrap = function ( element, settings ) {

        var container = document.createElement('div');
        container.setAttribute( 'class', settings.modalClass + ' ' + settings.effect + ' ' + settings.userClass );
        container.innerHTML = '<div class="'+settings.innerClass+'">' + element.outerHTML + '</div>';

        element.parentNode.replaceChild( container, element );

        return container;
    },


    Modality = function ( element, options ) {

        var inst = this; 

        inst.defaults = _defaults;
        inst.id       = element.getAttribute( 'id' );
        inst.settings = _extend( {}, _defaults, options );
        inst.wrapper  = _wrap( element, inst.settings );
        inst.triggers = document.querySelectorAll( 'a[href="#'+inst.id+'"], [data-modality="#'+inst.id+'"]' );
        inst.modal    = document.getElementById( inst.id );

        if( inst.settings.autoBind ) {
            for( var i = 0; i < inst.triggers.length; i++ )
                inst.setTrigger( inst.triggers[i] );
        }

        if( inst.settings.clickOffToClose ) {
            _addEvent( inst.wrapper, "click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); if(e.target == inst.wrapper) inst.close();
            }, false );
        }

        if( inst.settings.closeOnEscape ) {
            _addEvent( _body, "keyup", function (e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 27) inst.close();
            }, false);
        }

        if( inst.modal.style.display == 'none' ) inst.modal.style.display = '';

        if( inst.settings.openOnLoad ) inst.open();



        return inst;

    };




    _extend( Modality.prototype, {

        open: function ( callback ) {

            addClass( [this.wrapper, _body], this.settings.openClass );

            if ( typeof this.settings.onOpen == 'function' ) this.settings.onOpen();
            if ( typeof callback == 'function' ) callback();

            return this;

        },

        close: function ( callback ) {


            removeClass( [this.wrapper, _body], this.settings.openClass );


            if ( typeof this.settings.onClose == 'function' ) this.settings.onClose();
            if ( typeof callback == 'function' ) callback();

            return this;

        },

        toggle: function ( callback ) {
            return ( this.isOpen() ) ? this.close(callback) : this.open(callback);
        },

        isOpen: function () {
            return hasClass( this.wrapper, this.settings.openClass );
        },

        setTrigger: function ( trigger ) {

            var inst = this; // set local var for instance

            _addEvent( trigger, "click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); inst.toggle(); 
            }, false );

            return inst;
        }

    });

    _extend( Modality, { 

        instances: {}, 
        extend: _extend, 

        init: function ( query, options ) {
            var a = {}, e = document.querySelectorAll(query);
            for( var i = 0; i < e.length; i++ ) {
                var inst = new this( e[i], options );
                this.instances[ inst.id ] = a[i] = inst;
            }
            return ( a[1] === undefined ) ? a[0] : a;
        }

    });


    window[ _name ] = Modality;


})();
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Does it not follow the link at all, or does it open it in the current window instead of a new window?

Comment: It doesn't follow it at all. It only opens when you right click on the link telling it to open in a new window.

Comment: I simplified the code to it's basic elements Sumurai8

Comment: How I can get the a href link to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all put `http://` before the url in the anchor in order to let the browser redirect you to an external page, just like this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">Go to youtube</a>
```

Answering to your problem, your error is right here:

```
if( inst.settings.clickOffToClose ) {
    _addEvent( inst.wrapper, "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); if(e.target == inst.wrapper) inst.close();
    }, false );
}
```

You are preventing the 'Close' anchor but also the 'Go to Youtube' anchor from doing the link

You can do something like this to fix the problem:

```
if( inst.settings.clickOffToClose ) {
    _addEvent( inst.wrapper, "click", function(e) {
        if(e.target == inst.wrapper) {
            e.preventDefault();
            inst.close();
        }
    }, false );
}
```

Just preventing the 'Close' anchor